# Kotlin extension function failed to compile in java

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

I've defined the following extension function

```
fun <T> T.showAppPresentation(
    appPresentable: Maybe<AppPresentable>,
    appPresentationView: AppPresentationView,
    closeListener: () -> Unit
) where T : Fragment, T : FragmentPresentable {
    TODO()
}
```

where `Fragment` is an android `Fragment` and `FragmentPresentable` is an interface. It shows no error in Android Studio. When I try to compile my code, I got the following errors:

```
FragmentPresentableExtensionsKt.java:12: error: <identifier> expected
    public static final <T extends androidx.fragment.app.Fragment & FragmentPresentable>void showAppPresentation(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
                                                                    ^
FragmentPresentableExtensionsKt.java:12: error: illegal start of type
    public static final <T extends androidx.fragment.app.Fragment & FragmentPresentable>void showAppPresentation(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
                                                                                      ^
FragmentPresentableExtensionsKt.java:12: error: '(' expected
    public static final <T extends androidx.fragment.app.Fragment & FragmentPresentable>void showAppPresentation(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
                                                                                       ^
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The error message was initially formatted as a quote (using `>`), I edited to use a code block, so that it respects the spaces and indentation (which is important in this error). Could you please re-paste your initial error message in the code block to realign the text faithfully?

Comment: As a side note, any reason to use `Maybe` instead of nullable type?

Comment: @Joffrey My indention is no better than the one you already did. As for the `Maybe` the data comes from Rx which does not accept nullable type.

Comment: thanks for your reply. This is weird. Please scroll to the right. You're saying the arrows of the error messages really point to the second "p" of `showAppPresentation` and the second "t" of `showAppPresentation` respectively? Also there really is no space between `>` and `void`?

Comment: @Joffrey Fixed. All the arrows are more or less pointing to `FragmentPresentable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: `FragmentPresentable` was inside a package named `interface` which is a keyword in java/kotlin. It caused the issue at compile time. I moved `FragmentPresentable` inside a package `view` and now everything is working as expected.